# C++ dynamic array, push_back w/o STL

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

i got stuck with dynamic arrays. I want to read ints from a text file and store them into the array. I need a push_back and size function but cant use the STL from vector. I tried to do a push_back function but i need to use the size function for this. For the size function i thought of going through the array and  increment a counter for each element, but how do i stop the loop, e.g. for (int i = 0; i < d_array.end(); i++), to use .end() I need to include `<array>` ?

Thanks for hints.

my code so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int* d_array = 0;

    const string filename = "test.txt";
    int s = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    fstream f;
    f.open(filename, ios::in);

    if (f){
        while (f >> s){
            counter += 1;
        }
    }

    d_array = new int[counter];

    if (f){
        while (f >> s){
            d_array.push_back(s);
        }
        f.close();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < d_array.size(); i++){
        cout << d_array[i] << "\n";
    }


    void push_back(int value){
        int d_size = d_array.size();
        int* d2_array = 0;
        d2_array = new int[d_size + 1];
        d_array = d2_array;
        d_array[d_size] = value;
        delete[] d2_array;
    }

    int size() const{

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to include <array> ?    "<array>" is missing above

Comment: `int *` isn't a class and doesn't have member functions (like `push_back`). You have to do it yourself and keep track of the size yourself. And `std::array` isn't dynamic.

Comment: @fennek Neither arrays nor pointers have member functions. So you can not use push_back or size with pointers or arrays.

Comment: "I'm learning how to implement dynamic arrays", assuming its accurate, is a much better description of your situation than "I can't use `vector`", to which the right response is "figure out how to use `vector`".

Comment: If you can't use `std::vector`, then you need to re-implement `std::vector`, at least mostly. Not being able to use a pre-provided implementation does not change the fact that not using *an* implementation is very silly.

Comment: I think there may be too many misconceptions and mistakes in this code and question to give a single, coherent answer.  You may benefit the most by going back to your C++ book and trying some simpler tasks.

Comment: If this is an exercise given to you, you're almost certainly expected to implement a *class* that represents the dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question. You're trying to solve the question

> How can I find the length of a dynamically allocated array, given just the pointer to its beginning

which has no solution in general — but the question you actually need to solve is

> How do I make a data structure that contains a dynamically allocated array so that I can obtain the size of the array?

which has a really simple solution, once you stop getting hung up on the question you're focusing on....

Comment: This is good advice.  But it's more of a comment, since it doesn't really answer the question.